# Как инвертировать Tkinter.canvas() по вертикали

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Есть ли в Tkinter функция зеркального отражения холста или всё нужно писать вручную? То есть вот как должно быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как получилось у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это объекты на canvas (созданные, например, через create_line), то только вручную (получить все объекты на canvas, поменять их координаты, или все удалить, нарисовать с нуля). Если к canvas привязано изображение, а на нем уже все нарисовано, то можно отразить изображение средствами PIL.

Comment: @insolor то есть отразить можно только готовое изображение?

Comment: "Одной командой" - да. А так не вижу особой проблемы в том, чтобы координаты пересчитать, значит можно и не только готовое изображение.